# ¿Por qué no se cargan scripts de JS a menos que los incluya dentro de <head> y <body>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" class="logo">
            <span><img src="imagenes/banner.png" alt="UNIDEP" width="250px"/></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and <span>toggle</span> get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UNIDEP</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="alta.php">Registrar</a></li>
            <li><a href="consulta.php">Consultas</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mensajes</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Publicaciones</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div id="anuncio" class="jumbotron">
  <h1 align="center">Bootstrapin'</h1>
  <p align="center">Dandole sazón a HTML</p>
  <p align="center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.7/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip" role="button">Descargar!</a></p>
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-nav" >
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\contacto.png" alt="" /> Contacto </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\asistencia.png" alt="" /> Asistencia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\manual.png" alt="" /> Manual </a> </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\quiencreo.png" alt=""> Creador</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="bottom-footer">
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <ul class="footer-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\facebook.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\google-plus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imagenes\gorjeo.png" alt="" /></a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
```

Como pueden ver estan las tags de `<script>` al final, así acostumbro hacerlo pero esta vez tengo el problema de que si no están dentro de `<head></head>` y `<body></body>` en la misma página, no están funcionando mis menús desplegables y demás funciones de Bootstrap, no tengo idea de por qué está sucediendo esto. Se utilizaron diferentes navegadores, editores y computadoras con el mismo código y fue el mismo resultado.

Comment: Verificó la consola del navegador si lanza algún error. Quizá rutas  incorrectas. Y jquery va antes de bootstrap

Comment: intercambia las ultimas dos lineas `jquery.js` va primero que `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Eso arreglo el problema, me siento un poco tonto XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap requiere de Jquery. Así que jquery debe cargarse antes.  Si no hay problemas de rutas eso debería solucionar el error

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

La llamada a JQuery debe estar antes de la llamada a Bootstrap. Solo debes intercambiar éstas líneas:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
```

por

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```